# Unexpected error from database adapter: `select` failed ("badConnection")

Tags: sails.js

I am using the sails.js framework and sails_sql adaptor in my project. I try to connect with the server database I am getting below error.

Unexpected error from database adapter: `select` failed ("bad connection").  A connection either could not be obtained or there was an error using the connection.

error: [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND admin
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)

my config.datastores file

```
module.exports.datastores = {
  default: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    user: 'admin',
    password: "bfq5UrAGBMCjtwZ7*********",
    host: 'dreamgdev.cbk8fdmlwb5h.a******.com',
    database: 'Dre***',
    debug: ["ComQueryPacket"]
  },
};
```

Comment: Have you attempted to connect to the mySQL db itself using that connection info? What happens?

Comment: I am trying to connect rds server in  sails

Comment: you should attempt to connect to your instance first through `psql` to ensure that the db instance is up and configured correctly.